# Method/Event to get new number of markers after an update on the template

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

What I'm trying to do is use a template to create Google Map Markers.

```
<google-map id="google-map" map="{{map}}" latitude="44.6" longitude="-84.5" zoom="6" drag-events="true" api-key="{{key}}" single-info-window="true">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response}}" id="d" as="marker">
    <google-map-marker map="{{map}}" latitude="{{marker.lat}}" longitude="{{marker.lng}}">{{marker.EventName}}</google-map-marker>
  </template>
</google-map>
```

Then I'd like to use the MarkerClusterer https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer to create clusters. What's going on is that when I update the template, I can't figure out what event to use to get the `_updateMarkers` after it does the update. I can see in the `_updateMarkers` the before and after value after the update. The problem is that I don't see a method/event that I can use to fire something back with the updated marker count.

I've tried to use `dom-ready` with the template, but that only has the old value for the number of markers, it's always one behind. Example is if I have 7 markers on a map, then I do a zoom and maybe have 5 markers, it will return 7 markers and then after another zoom 5.

As I said I know the `_updateMarkers` is working, I'd just like to know if there's an event/method I can use to then call the MarkerClusterer function and re-create the MarkerCluster with the new values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although not a direct answer to your question you could check out the [google-map-markerclusterer](https://github.com/timeu/google-map-markerclusterer) element that I created some while ago. It contains all the functionality of the JS library and additional allows you to customize the clusters and markers.

Comment: I tried using it and it doesn't work correctly when using iron-ajax. It's one call behind. I sort of found a fix. I need to use an async call with a timeout

Comment: If you create an issue in the repo, I can take a look and see what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

Add `on-rendered-item-count-changed` ([docs](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/Polymer/polymer/elements/dom-repeat#event-rendered-item-count-changed)) event to your `dom-repeat` element. Done!